# difference btw local account and github account?

Tags: github

What is the difference between the local account that I set in git bash with git config --global user.name and my actual github account login. I have a test repo, in there I have added a few collaborators. When I push to the repo, the history will show my local name and not my github account username. How come ?

Comment: Your GitHub account is just how you authenticate to the remote, it is **not** necessarily the same details as the author/committer of the commits you're pushing.

Comment: Then what does it mean if I add someone as a collaborator to my private test repo, how does it show that he has write access, if he is using his local account to commit and push?

Comment: They will *also* have to log in using their GitHub credentials to push to that remote.

Comment: I understand. but how does the fact that I am adding their github account as a collaborator make sure that  they are using their local account to push ?

Comment: What "local account"? It doesn't say *anything* about the details they're adding to the commits, it just gives their GH account access to the remote.

Comment: By local account I am referring to the username that u set using the command git config --global user.name.

Comment: Again, that's irrelevant in terms of authentication to push to the GitHub remote.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is not git. GitHub is a remote repository management application. It has its own authentication and account system. You can push git repositories to it so that they can be shared and controlled.

The "local" variables that you set through git config are ways to make it faster to set the author of a commit.

There is nothing stopping you from pushing commits authored by someone who is "not you" to a GitHub remote that you control. I believe they will be associatively "linked" if the emails match, but it's not enforced or required.